# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$,$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{x^2-n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am having problems to find the values of x for which the following series converge. I understand the use of root test or ratio test to find the radius of convergence when the series is a power series, but in these cases I don't see how to do it, or if I have to use the definition.

(a)$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$

(b)$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{x^2-n^2}$

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry if one of this series has already be solved here. I tried to find it, but I did not have lucky.

I was just thinking that usually we use those tests for power series or series with factorial terms, since in such cases terms usually cancel and we have something nice to work. In this exercise the ratio test give us,
$\frac{n}{n+1}\frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x^{n+1}}$
which I don't see how it helps (In the comment section jimjim showed me that this means than the ratio test fails since the limit goes to 1). Something similar happens when I use the root test and, both of them in the second case. I end with something that it is not easier to work. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: what is special about those tests to make them work for power series only? have you tried them with these series?

Comment: Oh, no really. I was just thinking that usually we use those tests for power series or series with factorial terms, since in such cases terms usually cancel and we have something nice to work. In this exercise the ratio test give us $\frac{n}{n+1}\frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x^{n+1}}$ which I don't see how it helps. Something similar happens when I use the root test and both of them in the second case. I end with something that it is not easier to work. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Then you can say that ratio test fails ( goes to 1 and therefore inconclusive) where as root test succeeds, there are more general tests than those two, condensation test and Raab and kummer tests. you were on the right path just didnt mention what failed or why it did not seem to help. Please add what you said in your comment to your question, it shows and helps others to be of help :)

Comment: I didn't mean to say ratio test fails, but that if that the value of $\frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x^{n+1}}$ is less than 1 then it converges, so those are the values that series would converge for, as $\frac{n}{n+1}$ goes to 1 ( from below ). The common terminology when ratio test goes to 1 is ratio test fails, as it is inconclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

First series: For $|x| <1$ compare with $\sum x^{n}$ to prove convergence. For $|x| >1$ use that fact that $|\frac {x^{n}} {1-x^{n}}| \geq \frac {|x|^{n}} {1+|x|^{n}}$ and compare with $ \sum \frac 1 n$ to prove divergence The series is not defined at $x=\pm 1$

Second series: Not defined when $x$ is an integer. For other $x$ compare with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}}$ to prove convergence.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is all clear now.

Comment: Sorry again, I was trying to make the case when $|x|>1$ and I got stuck. I have made the following:

Comment: $$\| \frac{x^n}{1-x^n} \| \geq  \frac{|x|^n}{1+|x|^n}\geq \frac{|x|^n}{|x|^n+|x|^n} = \frac{1}{2}.$$ So, we have two cases: the first one if $\frac{x^n}{1-x^n} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ then by comparison test, the series diverges as $\frac{1}{2}\Sigma\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. But, if $ \frac{x^n}{1-x^n} \leq -\frac{1}{2} $ I don't know how to say that the series diverges. Or is it sufficient condition for $|b_n|\leq |a_n|$  to say that if $\Sigma b_n$ diverges, then $\Sigma a_n$ diverges too?  It seem to me that I can say that my series does not converge absolutely but maybe it does conditionally. :(

Comment: @sebsmay Here is an easy argument for $x <-1$: Write $\frac {x^{n}} {1-x^{n}}$ as $ 1- \frac 1 {1-x^{n}}$. Use the fact that $\sum \frac 1n \frac 1 {1-x^{n}}$ is absolutely convergent and $\sum \frac 1 n$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

(b) Series determination is $A=\mathbb{R}$\ $\mathbb{Z}$.

For $x\in A$, exist $k\in \mathbb{N}: k>|x|$, then $\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{x^2-n^2}$ is alternating series, it convergers by Leibniz.

So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{x^2-n^2}$ converges $\forall x\in A$

Comment: Thank you. I see it now.